# How to get help on specific methods in the interactive shell of MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, shell

In the interactive shell in MongoDB, `db.help()` lists (all) methods that can be used for (the current) database context.

**But how can I get information on how to use the method `db.logout()`?**

Calling `db.<collectionName>.help()` lists (all) functions available for (the selected) collection.

**But how can I get information on how to use the method `db.<collectionName>.logout()`?**

**Why is `db.<collectionName>.exists()` not listed?**

Calling `db.<collectionName>.find().help()` lists (all) cursor-functions.

**But how can I get information on the usage of the method `db.<collectionName>.find().sort()`?**

Comment: Full docs on the shell commands can be found at: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/

Comment: And the first line of output in what you listed produces: `find() modifiers  .sort( {...} )` Where `{ ... }` is inherrently a representation of an object with keys. Anyhow this [search](https://www.google.com/?q=mongodb%20.sort()) Oddly gets this [top result](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/)

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to review a limited details about the usage of a certain method, you can type the method without brackets and ENTER to get the JavaScript code. For example, type `db.c.find` and ENTER (Any collection name is available). If you need to get more details about the usage of a certain method, you may should read them from the [manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/method/).